# Use T-SQL to transpose two text columns

Tags: t-sql, row, transpose

Can I use a T-SQL query to transpose rows of text data from this:

[image]

to columns like this:

[image]

where the number of trainings a person can attend varies?

Comment: Do **not** post images of table. Paste the `CREATE` statements of them and some `INSERT` statements with sample data for the as **text**. [Edit] the question and change that. While at it, also show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.). And tell us which column(s) define the order of the rows and if it's always a maximum of three or if there can be more.

Comment: I've upvoted your question because it's important to find solutions for real problems that are not easily handled by the set-based logic of SQL.
It is very important that you post your own efforts to solve it, even if it didn't work. 
Often I see a question where they posted their approach and it gives a clue to something that works.
If you want more people to help out, post CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements so they can concentrate on the problem, as stickybit says. 
And as stickybit said, no images!!

Comment: Ugh - I should know better, but I was both frustrated and in a hurry, which is never a good combination. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps. If any ID has more than 3 training courses, the excess training courses will not appear.

```
SELECT OrgDefinedID
    , max(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN attended END) Attendance1
    , max(CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN training END) Training1
    , max(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN attended END) Attendance2
    , max(CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN training END) Training2
    , max(CASE WHEN row_num = 3 THEN attended END) Attendance3
    , max(CASE WHEN row_num = 3 THEN training END) Training3

FROM
(SELECT row_number() over (partition by OrgDefinedID order by Attended, Training) as row_num, *  
FROM T1) x 
group by OrgDefinedID
```

What is the `max()` doing? My first attempt was this

```
SELECT OrgDefinedID
    , (CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN attended END) Attendance1
    , (CASE WHEN row_num = 1 THEN training END) Training1
    , (CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN attended END) Attendance2
    , (CASE WHEN row_num = 2 THEN training END) Training2
    , (CASE WHEN row_num = 3 THEN attended END) Attendance3
    , (CASE WHEN row_num = 3 THEN training END) Training3

FROM
(SELECT row_number() over (partition by OrgDefinedID order by Attended, Training) as row_num, *  
FROM T1) x
```

which is almost there. We just need to collapse multiple rows into one row

| OrgDefinedID | Attendance1 | Training1 | Attendance2 | Training2 | Attendance3 | Training3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13076 | Yes | CPIE Online Training Studio | null | null | null | null |
| 13076 | null | null | Yes | AIDI | null | null |
| 12505478 | Yes | Best Practices 3, 9AM | null | null | null | null |
| 12505478 | null | null | Yes | Work Smarter II, #4 | null | null |
| 12505478 | null | null | null | null | Yes | Rubric Design 2 |

You can see that within a given OrgDefinedID, each column has a single non-null value and the other values in that column are null. So if we group by OrgDefinedID and apply max(), it will pick the non-null value we want.
Note that aggregate functions like max() ignore nulls.
So adding the max() function and grouping by OrgDefinedID, we get:

| OrgDefinedID | Attendance1 | Training1 | Attendance2 | Training2 | Attendance3 | Training3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13076 | Yes | CPIE Online Training Studio | Yes | AIDI | null | null |
| 12505478 | Yes | Best Practices 3, 9AM | Yes | Work Smarter II, #4 | Yes | Rubric Design 2 |

Comment: Thank you - this helped a lot of people and helped me learn a couple new things!